# bash scp no such file or directory

Tags: bash, file, scp

I am using this code to copy a directory with all of its sub-directories from a remote server to local disk.

```
scp -q -r userbane@ip:/var/myFolder /home/
```

It copies all files except 2 which gives this error

```
scp: /var/myFolder/file1.txt: No such file or directory
scp: /var/myFolder/file2.txt: No such file or directory
```

But both files DO exist.
Any help?

Comment: do you have the right to read?

Comment: Can you do a `ls -l` on them ? Are they in any way special (for example I notice the path is different) ?

Comment: Yes I can read them.

and @cnicutar Sorry about that it was a typo. I got this when I `ls -l` on the files `lrwxrwxrwx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> I got this when I `ls -l` on the files `lrwxrwxrwx`
>                                         ^
> ```

They are symlinks. It's most likely the paths they point to are inaccessible.

Comment: @Matin When you say `ls -l`, doesn't it say a `-> something` right at the end ? Can you acess *that* path ?

Comment: Yes It does. And wow I can't even see those folders. I dont think I have access. That's the error than. Thank you. +1. But now can I make the `scp` command copy only files that ends with `xml` ?

Comment: How about `find ./ -iname '*.xml' | xargs scp_script.sh`. And in your `scp_script` do `shift; scp "$@" userbane@ip:`.

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand what xargs do and what do you mean by shift? (I'm a beginner). Also don't forget that I have lots of xml files in different sub-directories (I need a recursive copying that wherever it sees *.xml, it copies it)

Comment: I don't think `find` + `scp` are right for this. How about rsync ? `rsync -avz --include='*.xml' --exclude='*'`.

Comment: Great Job. :D!! It doesn't give that error. but I have 2 little questions. 1. is `rsync` installed by default on most linux? because i'm building this for someone who will use it on different linux. and 2. Although the errors disappeared, the command is still copying some `*.cnf` files !!!!!

Comment: @Matin Well no, `rsync` isn't available everywhere so you need to consider that too. As for the `.cnf` files, I probably messed up the `include` and `exclude` patterns so you need to tweak them a little.

Comment: So no way to do the same with `scp` :( I'd rather `scp`